# Divide numbers of a string column for another column in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Starting from a dataset with the string column "code_input", I would (by Python) to divide only numbers for a column "days".
I would preserve the rest of string in a column "code_output".

Example of my dataset:

| code_input | days | code_output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 15.5C + 72HT | 3 | 5.16C + 24HT |
| 46C + 28HT +6T | 2 | 23C + 14HT + 3T |
| ... | ... | ... |

Thank u!

Comment: "I need this" is not a valid question on SO. [ask]

Comment: I'm blocked on this step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you have a pandas dataframe:

```
>>> df
       code_input  days
0    15.5C + 72HT     3
1  46C + 28HT +6T     2
```

You have to iterate over each row. You can use a callable as `repl` parameter of `re.sub`:

```
import re

# Python >= 3.8 for walrus operator
df['code_output'] = [re.sub(r'([\d.]+)', lambda x: str(int(x) if (x := float(x[0]) / row.days) - int(x) == 0 else round(x, 2)), row.code_input)
                         for row in df.itertuples()]
```

Output:

```
>>> df
       code_input  days     code_output
0    15.5C + 72HT     3    5.17C + 24HT
1  46C + 28HT +6T     2  23C + 14HT +3T
```

The `lambda` function divide each number by the current number of days and try to simplify the number: downcast to `int` if possible else return a rounded `float`.

```
str(int(x) if (x := float(x[0]) / row.days) - int(x) == 0 else round(x, 2))
```

Comment: It's correct, it is a pandas dataframe. BTW it raises an error "float division by zero", but I don't understand where... can u help me please?

Comment: Check rows where days=0. `df[df['days'] == 0]`. What do you want to do in this case?

Comment: I haven't row with days=0 :(
Could be the case "46.0C + 28.0HT +6T"?

Comment: Maybe you have something like `'0HT'`

Comment: How can i manage this case? I would receive 0HT in that case, after the division.

Comment: @Jresearcher. I will try. However I need to know if a case like 'T' should be considered as '1T' and if days=3 the output would be '0.33T'? Also, do you have case where you have a constant without a letter?

Comment: All letters are preceded by a number. So you can't find T but you will find 1T (0.33 after the division). Similarly, all numbers precede a letter. I can't have 3. Also, letters with 0 (Es. 0HT + 0C) returned "0HT + 0C" after the division. Thank you!

Comment: Instead of check if `x / int(x) == 1`, I prefer verify if `x - int(x) == 0` to avoid the `ZeroDivisionError`. Can you check it please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254073/discussion-between-jresearcher-and-corralien).

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what your initial data structure looks like

But for the string parsing and dividing, you could use regular expression to extract numbers from your string, and then divide them by "days"

after that you just have to "re-concatenate" your string to get the final result

Example :

```
import re

def get_number(code_input, days):

    numbers = re.split(r'(\d+)', code_input)
    
    all_number = []
    for num in numbers:
        if num.isdigit():
            all_number.append(str(int(num) // days))
        else:
            all_number.append(num)
    
    code_output = ''.join(all_number)
    return code_output


input_dic = {"code_input": "46C + 28HT + 6T", "days": "2"}

code_output = get_number(input_dic["code_input"], int(input_dic["days"]))
print(code_output)
```

prints `23C + 14HT + 3T`